# LINQ group by doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
from p in Products
join c in Categories on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
group p by p.Category into prices
select new {price = prices.Average(p => p.UnitPrice), name = p.Category.CategoryName }
```

The error I get is:

```
The name 'p' does not exist in the current context
```

Why can't I access p here? What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Key`:

```
...
group p by p.Category into prices
select new 
{
    price = prices.Average(p => p.UnitPrice), 
    name = prices.Key.CategoryName 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea WHY I have to use Key here?

Comment: @Bv202: because you cannot access `p` here, it is out of scope.  You can access the product-group(which can contain multiple products). The `Category` is the key of the group, therefore you can use the `Key` property.